# Deleting data from Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, delete-row

I am new to Android development, I have a Listview in may app, Listview is populated with data from Sqlite database. I want to use check boxes on this listview & delete selected item.
I want to clear selected data rows form Sqlite Db indeed.
Any useful help will be appreciated.

First i have retrieved SMS in my app as follows:`
            if (bundle != null) {

```
            //—retrieve the SMS message received—
            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

            for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                timestamp = smsMessage[n].getTimestampMillis();

                number = smsMessage[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                body += smsMessage[n].getDisplayMessageBody();
                abortBroadcast();
                blockMessage(context);
            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
private void blockMessage(Context context) {

    // instantiate DbMNager object to insert sms in database
    //formating receiving time:
    //SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d  HH:mm:ss a");
    String formatedTime = formatter.format(timestamp);
    DBmanager= new DbManager(context);
    DBmanager.open();
    DBmanager.Insert_sms_data(formatedTime ,number,body);
    DBmanager.close();`
```

Then stored in SQlite DB as follows :

```
public void Insert_sms_data(String formatedTime, String number, String body){
    try{

        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(SMS_Time, formatedTime);
        cv.put(PHONE_NUMBER, number);
        cv.put(MESSAGE_BODY, body);
        DB.insert(TABLE_SMS, null, cv);
        DB.close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR in insertion", ex.toString());
    }

}

public Cursor Return_All(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+"SMS_TABLE", null);
    return cur;

}
// Clear all messaged
public void ClearAll(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this .getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_SMS, null, null);
    db.close();
}
```

After that retrieved in my listview Activity successfully.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listViewSMS;
Context context;
DbManager manager;
Button btn_clearall;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
//array from is the column name in your cursor where you're getting the data 

String[] from = new String[]{"Phone_number","Message_body","Time"};
//array toIDs contains the id of textViews


int[] toIDs = new int[]{R.id.textViewSMSSender,R.id.textViewMessageBody,R.id.textViewMSMStime};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_activity_main);
    context=this;
    //get the ListView Reference
    try{
        listViewSMS=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS);
        listViewSMS.setChoiceMode(listViewSMS.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        manager = new DbManager(context);
        cursor = manager.Return_All();

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_each_item, cursor, from, toIDs);
        listViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //refreshCursor();

        listViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                int itemId = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(position));
                cursor.moveToPosition(itemId);
                int messageId = cursor.getInt(0);
                deleteMessage(messageId);

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "current position"+itemId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    TextView tv_SMSSenderNumber=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSMSSender);
                                    TextView tv_SMSBody=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageBody);
                                    TextView tv_SMSTime=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewMSMStime);
                                    String smsSender=tv_SMSSenderNumber.getText().toString();
                                    String smsBody= tv_SMSBody.getText().toString();
                                    String smsTime= tv_SMSTime.getText().toString();    
            }

        });

    }

    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e("ERROR!!", ex.toString());
    }


    btn_clearall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Delall);
    btn_clearall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearMessages(); 
            //refreshCursor();
```

//          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
        }
    });

    CheckBox cb_sms_lv = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_smslist);


}

protected void clearMessages() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle(R.string.delete)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.clear_message_confirm))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.delete,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                    manager = new DbManager(
                            context);
                    manager.open();
                    manager.ClearAll();
                    manager.close();
                    refreshCursor();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                }
            }).show();
}

private void deleteMessage(final int messageId){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle(R.string.delete)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_message_confirm))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.delete,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                    manager = new DbManager(
                            context);
                    manager.open();
                    manager.deleteMessage(messageId);
                    manager.close();
                    refreshCursor();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                }
            }).show();
}

public void refreshCursor() {
    manager = new DbManager(context);
    manager.open();
    cursor = manager.Return_All();

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_each_item, cursor, from, toIDs);
    listViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);
    manager.close();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I can delete the whole thread successfully but now i wantt to delete few sms from listview using checkbox
Any helpful tutorial please?

Comment: use the custom adapter for the list view

Comment: So us some code what have you done ?

Comment: Please show some code as in much you've done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Code to delete item from listview

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(position+"");
                ArrayList.remove(index);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then use the Query to delete data from Sqite database

Answer (score 1):

A little tip could help. Since you have the data with you, keep track of the items tick marked. Store their ids. Once the user clicks on done or whatever button you have, run an sql query that deletes the records with the ids. And then call `notifyDataSetChanged` of the list view. Since its a cursor there are changes that `notifyDataSetChanged` might not function well then refill the cursor once again.

Refer to [Refresh ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656841/android-listview-delete-item-and-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

if you succesfully remove data from databse as you say in your question than use notifydatasetchanged method of listview to reload listview with new data.

Answer (score 1):

For Custom Adapter use the list item row xml as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/data"
        android:checked="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the custom adapter java class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<String> mlistdata;
    private LayoutInflater layoutinflater;
    private Context mContext;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> elements)
    {
        mlistdata = elements;
        layoutinflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext=context;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mlistdata.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int arg0, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertview==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertview = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_items, null);
            holder.txt=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.data);
            holder.cb=(CheckBox)convertview.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertview.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
        }
        holder.txt.setText((mlistdata.get(arg0)).toString());

    holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(holder.cb.isChecked())
            {
            //database related operation
         }
          else
        {
        //database related operation
         }
            }

    });


    return convertview;
}
static class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView txt;
    CheckBox cb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations. very useful..you can see demo at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haarman.listviewanimations

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution [here](http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2011/10/custom-listview-with-checkbox.html)

in EmployeeAdapter.java you will have checked and unchecked dataList and to get that write a methode `getDataList();` in this file.

Example :

```
public List<employeemodel> getDataList(){
    return employeeData;
}
```

use this method in your activity using `yourAdapter.getDataList();`

after getting datalist perform the delete operation and set new dataList to your adapter and call `yourListView.notifyDatasetChange();`.

Answer (score 0):

custom adapter and  `notifyDataSetChanged()`